# How to tell YouTube to avoid autoplaying certain artists?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I like to hear a certain artist so usually I google one of her songs, enter YouTube to hear it, and after it ends YouTube autoplays a bunch of other songs of hers, which is great. But what always happens is that after four or five songs it starts playing another artist (Taylor Swift), which I really don't like.

To make the AI understand I don't like her I usually try to stop her songs immediately after they start and pick another artist to hear. But I guess the AI is not that smart so every time I want to hear music and start with my selected artist, after a short while it loops to Taylor Swift and Katy Perry (who are not my 'cup of tea').

The artist I am listening to is from the same genre I guess, so it makes sense for YouTube to do this, but I really want to avoid these artists.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after repeatedly watching a Madonna video to teach a song a student wanted to learn. No matter what song I started with after a couple of songs autoplay started playing Madonna. On the next to play song auto play list at the right side are three dots if you hover the mouse click on this and a drop down will let you say your not interested and the reason for example 'we watched before or I don't like this'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not yet.

Remember, YouTube was originally designed to be a video hosting site and not a *music sharing* service (but it's heading that way). The autoplay'd videos you watch are from the 'up next' sidebar which recommends other videos for you to watch next. These are typically based on a combination of what *other* users have watched following your video plus sponsored content folks pay to have added to that list.

You can exclude certain artists from your *search* by using the minus (-) operator, but that will *only* affect the search results and ***not*** what shows up in your recommended play list after:

> **YouTube Search:** `Beyoncé -"Taylor Swift"`  (this wont fix the autoplay list)

You can certainly turn *off* the 'autoplay' feature, but then you'll have to click on each video individually to listen to it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just block the user by going to their profile. Any media from them will be excluded, including all posts, video and music. It may not stop an artist if the person uploading isn't the artist as YouTube tends to have multiple uploaders from different sources.